# How do I flatten nested lists using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have a nested HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li> First Item </li>
  <li> Nested list:
    <ol>
      <li> One </li>
      <li> Two </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li> Third Item </li>
</ul>
```

Is it at all possible to flatten this into a line-by-line representation, where the nesting depth becomes an attribute value?  Something like this:

```
<line nest="1"> First Item </line>
<line nest="1"> Nested list: </line>
<line nest="2"> One </line>
<line nest="2"> Two </line>
<line nest="1"> Third Item </line>
```

I just can think of a way of doing this for deeply nested lists. What I have is the following:

```
<xsl:template match="ol | ul">                                                
  <xsl:apply-templates/>                                                      
</xsl:template>       

<xsl:template match="li">                                                     
  <line>                                            
    <xsl:attribute name="nest"><xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::ol|ancestor::up)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>                                                      
  </line>                                                                      
</xsl:template>
```

But this nests the `<line>` elements too, and it does not handle other elements like `<em>` text inside of a list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ul"> 
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>          
    </root>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="li">                                                     
    <line nest="{count(ancestor::ol|ancestor::ul)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ol or self::ul)]"/>                                                      
    </line> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ol | ul"/>                                                      
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="ol | ul">                                                     
    <xsl:apply-templates/>                                                      
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will preserve any HTML markup you might have within a `li` element.

Comment: Why is the identity transform required?

Comment: @Jens To "preserve any HTML markup you might have within a `li` element".

Comment: Isn't that achieved by the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)?

Comment: @Jens No. The built in template rules only copy the text, not the markup.

Comment: Regarding the identity transform: it also prevents my `<xsl:template match="*">` rule to match to capture elements that I forgot and that did not match, correct? I can't have both, can I?

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. What exactly does the template `<xsl:template match="*">` do?

Comment: It prints a `<xsl:message terminate="no">WARNING: Unmatched element: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:message>` and then continues to apply templates recursively. That way, whatever did not match falls through this one and I get a warning that I missed an element. It seems like a helpful debugging tool.

Comment: I am not sure I entirely understand this. The identity transform template will process any element (and other nodes) that isn't matched by a more specific (i.e. higher priority) template. So it is not possible to "miss an element".

Comment: Right :) But the processing using the identity transform is just a plain write-through, and as such misses elements that haven't been processed explicitly by providing a rule for them. I want to ensure that all my elements are covered by an explicit rule, and from the sounds of it the identity transform allows those to "slip through" (I'd insert a `<xsl:message>` though to catch that).

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need such thing (other than as a training tool, perhaps). In any case, if you're not willing to use a "catch-all" template to process the contents of `li`, then you will need a template to match them explicitly - i.e. enumerate **all** possible HTML tags that a `li` might carry.

Comment: I prefer to have to enumerate _all_ because there's some form of tinkering I have to do with them anyway. Just want to make sure that I provide a template for ever single one. :)

Comment: "*Just want to make sure that I provide a template for ever single one.*" I am not sure how exactly you can make sure of that. Either you know exactly which elements can appear in the input (and in such case you don't need to build your "trap"), or you don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77461/discussion-between-jens-and-michael-hor257k).

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `xsl:apply-templates` after the creation of the `line` elements, and change it to select non-text nodes. Inside the `line` element you then replace it with an `xsl:value-of` to get just the text.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="ol | ul">                                                
      <xsl:apply-templates/>                                                      
    </xsl:template>       

    <xsl:template match="li">                                                     
      <line nest="{count(ancestor::ol|ancestor::up)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>                                                      
      </line>                                                                      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::text())]" />                                                      
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in the creation of the `nest` attribute, to simplify the code.

Comment: Using `text()` prevents me from using other elements in a list item, for example `<em>`'ed text, right? Those would complicate the matter?

Comment: That is correct. michael.hor257k has shown the correct approach to take in these circumstances.